# How can I check if loggen API and hash is admin of chats?

Tags: python, telegram

I want to know how can I write a method in order to check by all irs group id's and channels if I am admin/owner of them?

I've tried chat gpt and it is no good and I can't find a great document for telethon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.